# Recommended HTML IDE for macOS

Tags: javascript, php, html-editor, autocomplete

I need a HTML IDE, which builds a full project (take Coffeecup Editor as an example) but for free.

I also need an auto-complete feature, and support for JavaScript and PHP.

Answer (score 2):

One of my favorite tools is [NetBeans](https://netbeans.org/). It can work with Java, JavaScript, HTML5, PHP, C/C++, Groovy, etc. It has code complete for [JavaScript](https://netbeans.org/kb/73/ide/javascript-editor.html) and [PHP](https://netbeans.org/features/php/index.html). It's written in Java, so it works on Mac, Windows and Linux and it's completely free!

Answer (score 0):

I use Brackets. It has autocomplete for some languages and you can add functionality with plugins.
You can get it for free on [brackets.io](http://brackets.io) and its opensource.
Before I switched to the Jetbrains tools, I used Brackets a lot. It has an active community, syntax highlighting and the posibillity to be extended eith plugins, like I already said.

Comment: Where to find it? Is it available for free? Have you used it, and thus can recommend it – or just heard about it? Please [edit] your answer and fill those gaps. Thanks!